# symfony file-input widget problem

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

in my RcProfileTableForm.class.php i have this line for file input:
  $this->widgetSchema['file']    = new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array('label' => 'Profile Pic'),array('class' => 'file_input'));

on my form i have the lable as Profile Pic as above, then the button to click to open the browser to choose the input file and next to that i have the wording "No file chosen".

if you do choose a file, the filename will appear there. my problem now is: i cannot find in all of my code where that string is defined - No file chosen?????  i need to make that string RED and cannot find it anywhere...is this a symfony(1.4.5) thing???

can some-one please help?
thank you

Comment: I suspect that "no file chosen" is actually a (browser-specific) part of the `<input type="file">` control (and thus can't be styled separately from the file selection box). What happens when you set the style of `.file_input` to `color:red` through CSS?

Answer (score 1):

just as Piskvor commented - it's a browser-specific. For example Firefox 4.0 doesn't show 'No file chosen' text (it shows text input field).

And the way to apply color (or other style) to the text is using CSS:

```
.file_input { color: red }
```

Regards.